# WPF-Prism CanExecute method not being called

Tags: wpf, prism, command

I am coding a simple login UserControl with two TextBoxes (Username and Password) and a Login button. I want the Login button to be enabled only when the username and password fields are filled in. I am using Prism and MVVM. The LoginViewModel contains a property called LoginCommand that is bound to the Login button. I have a CanLoginExecute() method in my ViewModel but it fires only when the application comes up and then never again. So the Login button is never enabled. What am I missing?

Here's my xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="username"
    Text="{Binding Path=Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<TextBox x:Name="password"
    Text="{Binding Path=Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<Button Content="Login"
    cmnd:Click.Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
```

Here's my ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        this.LoginCommand =
            new DelegateCommand<object>(
                this.LoginExecute, this.CanLoginExecute);
    }

    private Boolean CanLoginExecute(object dummyObject)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) ? false : true;
    }

    private void LoginExecute(object dummyObject)
    {
        if (CheckCredentials(Username, Password))
        {
            ....
        }
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Username")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
                    result = "Please enter a username";
            }
            else if (columnName == "Password")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                    result = "Please enter a password";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    #endregion // IDataErrorInfo Members

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    #region Properties

    private String _username;
    public String Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _username)
                return;
            _username = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Username");
        }
    }

    private String _password;
    public String Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _password)
                return;
            _password = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand { get; private set; }

    #endregion // Properties
}
```

Comment: What is cmnd:Click.Command= , Is it something Prism specific. I usually do <Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" And canexecute works for me.

Comment: Yes, cmnd:Click.Command= is prism specific:

xmlns:cmnd="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation"

Since I am using Prism's DelegateCommand, I thought this would be the compatible command binding mechanism. I have also tried straight Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" - it works exactly the same.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is most likely that the bound control is never asking for the *CanExecute* state again. You need to call the **RaiseCanExecuteChanged** method on the DelegateCommand whenever you detect a condition that changes the command's *CanExecute* state. This signals the bound control to update the *CanExecute* state.

Comment: Just for the record (this was happening to me), I wasn't finding the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method because I was using the ICommand interface. This method is defined in the DelegateCommand implementation, so I needed to cast it.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with Prism6 the `DelegateCommand` can "observe" your propertys. Means everytime your property is changing the CanExecute-Method is called. The good thing is you get rid of `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` in the Propertysetter. You can also chain-call that method if you want to observe more properties:

```
public LoginViewModel()
{
    this.LoginCommand =
        new DelegateCommand<object>(
            this.LoginExecute, this.CanLoginExecute).ObservesProperty(() => Username).ObservesProperty(() => Password);
}
```

Furthermore if you just want your DelegateCommand be called depending on the state of a boolean property you can use `.ObservesCanExecute(()=> BoolProp)`

```
public LoginViewModel()
{
    this.LoginCommand =
        new DelegateCommand<object>(
            this.LoginExecute).ObservesCanExecute(()=> IsServerOnline).ObservesProperty(() => Username).ObservesProperty(() => Password);
}
```

You dont need `this.CanLoginExecute` anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Code for RaiseCanExecuteChanged:

```
    private void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        DelegateCommand<object> command = LoginCommand as DelegateCommand<object>;
        command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public const string UsernameProperty = "Username";
    private String _username;
    public String Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(UsernameProperty);
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little workaround for Prism (tested with Prism.Core 7.1.0.431):

```
public class RelayCommand : DelegateCommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethode) : base(executeMethode)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethode, Func<bool> canExecuteMethode) : base(executeMethode, canExecuteMethode)
    {

    }

    public override event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```