# How to validate properties of the objects which belongs to a collection of a ViewModel via IDataErrorInfo interface

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have a **MyViewModel**, which contains scalar properties and collection properties.

```
public class MyViewModel :
    System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged,
    System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        List<SelectableObject> list = new List<SelectableObject>();
        foreach (var weekDay in System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectableObject() { Name = weekDay, IsSelected = false });
        }
        WeekDays = list;
    }
    public string Catalog { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationTime { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectableObject> WeekDays { get; private set; }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var errorResult = string.Empty;

            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "CreationTime":
                    // Validation logic
                    break;
                case "ModificationTime":
                    // Validation logic
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return errorResult;
        }
    }
}
```

**SelectableObject** class:

```
public class SelectableObject : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I want to manipulate **IsEnabled** property of the **<Button />** via **SaveCommand**, and I want it will enabled, only if there no errors on the form. But I can't figure out how to validate this: at least one WeekDay had to be selected.

Yes, I can listen for **PropertyChanged** event of every object in the **WeekDays** collection, but in this case validation logic will be separated from the **IDataErrorInfo** interface.

Is there any solution for this problem? How to put validation logic for collections to the **IDataErrorInfo** interface?

Answer (score 1):

simply do your logic in your canexecute?

viewmodel:

```
private DelegateCommand _save;

public ICommand SaveCommand
{
  get {return this._save ?? (this._save = new DelegateComamnd(this.MyExecuteMethod, this.MyCanExecuteMethod));}
 }

private bool MyCanExecuteMethod()
{
   return this.WeekDays.Any(x=>x.IsSelected) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Error);
}
```

ps: error should be non empty if there any errors.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? In your case I have to raise CanSaveCommandExecute any time when IsSelected property of weekdays is  changed - so I have to handle PropertyChanged event...

Comment: no no you dont have to raise anything - wpf do this for you. i dont know if you use RelayCommand or DelegateCommand but both have a CanExecute method and these method is called from CommandManager in wpf. you just have to provide this method. just try this out.

Comment: I use DelegateCommand from prism library. So every time property changed on the ViewModel I have to raise CanExecuteChanged. Its good way, because I'm control the moments when to raise the event.

Comment: i must admit that i have my own delegatecommand implementation with somthing like this in my CanExecute add/remove:  CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; i dont know where/how prism handle these behavior. do you get an automatic update to your command/Save Button if you try my solution and just update one weekday?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7353704/780798) guy explain why prism DelegateCommand will not updated automatically.

Comment: What I want to say - in your case validation logic will be divided into several parts (one from indexer, other one - in CanExecute method)